# getting values is stored in a Session variable object of array type... System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show values saved in object of array type..
by doing

```
<body>objname.Names</body>
```

this gets printed on my HTML page System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to print the values of Names you can use this format. Of course `objname` must be a protected or public member of the Page.

```
<body><%= string.Join(", ", objname.Names.ToArray()) %></body>
```

Comment: onof : hi can you tell me how to check for null values.if its value is null then it shows null reference error.

Answer (score 1):

you should loop at minimum, or use a Data bindable control like DataList, DataGrid, Repeater etc...

pseudo code:

```
foreach(object obj in objName)
{
  Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br />", obj.ToString())), 
}
```

of course the result of `obj.ToString()` depends very much on what kind of objects you have in your array or collection.

Comment: Thanks i din try this cz prev solution wrked.:) have a nice day